# Команда запуска .class файла из командной строки

Tags: java, netbeans, консоль

Создал проект в `NetBeans` (по книге П.Ноутона, Г. Шилдта "Java2. Наиболее полное руководство").

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package example2;

/**
 *
 * @author Asus
 */
/*
 * Другой короткий пример.
 * Файл "Example2.java"
 */ 
public class Example2 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int num; //объявляет переменную с именем num
        num=100; //присваивает num значение 100
        System.out.println("Значение num: "+num);
        num*=2;
        System.out.print("Удвоенное значение num: ");
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

При создании проекта был создан класс `example2.Example2` с папкой проекта `D:\ExamplesFromBook\Example2\Example2` (а расположение проекта соответственно `D:\ExamplesFromBook\Example2`). Создал байт-код с помощью команды в командной строке

```
D:\ExamplesFromBook\Example2\Example2\src\example2>javac Example2.java
```

в результате чего был создан файл `Example2.class`.Далее пытался разнообразными способами запустить .class файл из командной строки, среди которых, например, был такой:

```
D:\ExamplesFromBook\Example2\Example2>java example2.Example2
```

в результате чего получил ошибку

```
Error: Could not find or load main class example2.Example2
```

Какую команду необходимо использовать и из какой папки запускать?

Comment: Хм

     java example2/Example2

Comment: @alexlz из какой папки запускать эту команду (укажите конкртеный путь)?

Comment: Ну, вероятно, на уровень выше. Правда, согласно туториалу команда будет

      java example2.Example2

(как там, в виндах, будет `java example2/Example2` -- не знаю, у меня виндов нет). А в package вроде как раз путь и задаётся.)

Comment: @alexlz 

    D:\ExamplesFromBook\Example2>java example2.Example2 
не помогает. Вариант с `/` также не работает. Если есть `NetBeans`,то проделав все с самого начала (задав в настройках проекта тоже расположение и тот же путь и имя проекта), то можете убедится, что не работает и выдает ту же самую ошибку.

Comment: Неохота netbeans запускать. Но из /home/alex запускается

     java -classpath ./tmp example2.Example2

(директория example2 находится в /home/alex/tmp)

Answer (score 2):

В директории D:\ExamplesFromBook\Example2\Example2 создайте папку classes.

Затем,

```
D:\ExamplesFromBook\Example2\Example2>javac -classpath ./classes -d ./classes src/example2/Example2.java
```

После этого:

```
D:\ExamplesFromBook\Example2\Example2>java -classpath ./classes example2.Example2
```

Внимательно изучите статью:

http://skipy.ru/technics/likbez.html